# setOnClickListener return -1 History for android Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Im sorry to ask, this question might sound stupid but...=(..

How do I code `onclickListener` so that the activity return `-1` history??

you know basically like the return button that the phone already has.

if anyone know please tell me..=[

sorry again for asking such a dumb question.

Comment: call onBackPressed(); in onClick method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        myActivity.finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Or

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    finish(); //(or myActivity.finish());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add

```
activity.finish();
```

or simply

```
finish();
```

if your class already extends activity

to get previously stacked screen. Your currently activity will be finished